# horizontal offset for categorical plot

Tags: gnuplot, spacing

For the following categorical plot I would like to put some space left of the first category and right of the last:

```
#abc.dat
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

In gnuplot:

```
set yrange [0:4]
plot 'abc.dat' using 2:xticlabels(1) pointtype 7 pointsize 5
```

Result:

[image]

Desired (approximately):

[image]

How can this be done? I specifically want points (and not bars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `set offsets` adds a space between data and axes:

```
set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05
```

`graph ...` means a space relative to your plot size.